# return already casted object to the concrete class type

Tags: java, generics

Please see the method below.
Is there a way to cast the created object in a generic way and return the already casted object to the concrete class type, so the user will not have to cast it by himself?

```
public static  Object getObject(String xmlString, String fullyQualifiedClassName) throws Exception {

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        UploadDocument doc = (UploadDocument) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName);

        UploadResult result = DataUploaderUtil.createObject(doc);

        if (result != null) {
              Object uploadObject = result.getUploadObject();
              if (uploadObject != null && clazz.isInstance(uploadObject)) {
                    return uploadObject;
              }
        }
        return null;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the caller has the class object (which they do if they would have been able to cast manually):

```
public static <T> T getObject(String xmlString, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    ...
    return (T) uploadObject;
}
```

Invocation:

```
Foo f = getObject(someXml, Foo.class);
```

Comment: can you please explain the different from doing :                                                                                                             public static  <T> Object getObject(String xmlString, Class<T> clazz)
   throws Exception { .....  return  uploadObject;

Comment: `<T>` just declares that `T` is a generic parameter; you need to actually use `T` in various places in order for it to have any effect. With that code, the return type is still declared to be `Object`, while in my code, the return type is `T`. Since `Class<T>` is the type of the `clazz` parameter, this essentially says that the return type is whichever class is passed as a parameter.